# How to upload image to LinkedIn for Ugc image post in C#

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

So I am following [Linkedin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#creating-a-share-on-linkedin) for implementing Create Image Share on Linkedin.

The documentation lists three steps:

1. Register your image to be uploaded.
2. Upload your image to LinkedIn.
3. Create the image share.

While I am able to do the first step to get the *uploadUrl*, I am getting 400 response error with blank error message while doing step 2.

The documentation list the second step as:

```
curl -i --upload-file /Users/peter/Desktop/superneatimage.png --header "Authorization: Bearer redacted" 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQJbrN86Zm265gAAAWemyz2pxPSgONtBiZdchrgG872QltnfYjnMdb2j3A&app=1953784&sync=0&v=beta&ut=2H-IhpbfXrRow1'
```

Here's my step 2 in C# code:

```
private bool UploadImageBinaryFile(RequestUploadUrlResponse uploadDetails)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", #access_token#);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0");
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            string fileAddress = image_path + "image.png";
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileAddress);
            string name = "upload-file";
            form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes), name);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync
                (
                    uploadDetails.value.uploadMechanism.mediaUploadHttpRequest.uploadUrl,
                    form
            ).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)//<--getting 400 error Bad Request here
            {
                string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorResponseHandler(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have ensured that I was successfully able to the uploadUrl from the first step. And when I used the URL https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/*#id#* to check the status, I was able the see the status as *WAITING_UPLOAD*.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, basically we have to pass the binary in the content only, whereas I was passing it in the form.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);
        var content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileAddress));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //response is empty. Have to call the checkAssetStatus to see if the asset is 'AVAILABLE'
            string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        }
        else
        {
            //handleError();
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: People who return with a correct, working answer their own questions deserve more credit. I had also been inadvertently including my binary in the form rather than the content. Thank you for this!

Comment: Referenced your answer from my own post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77210097/3887554